# Unsupported operand types on CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a this

```
**Fatal_Error:
Error: Unsupported operand types    
File: C:\wamp\www\newsletter\lib\Cake\View\Helper\FlashHelper.php   
Line: 90**
```

every time I clicked the submit button. here's my code..

```
**AddsController.php //Controller**
<?php

    class AddsController extends AppController {
        public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
        public $components=array('Session');

        public function index() {

            if($this->request->is('post'))
            {
                $this->Add->create();
                $this->Add->save($this->request->data);
                $this->Session->setFlash('Success');
                return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
        }
    }
?>

**Add.php //Model/**
<?php

    App::uses('AppModel' , 'Model');
    class Add extends AppModel
    {
        public $name = "Add";
        public $useTable = 'request';
        public $primaryket = 'id';
        public $useDbConfig = 'default';
    }

?>

**index.ctp //View/Adds/index.ctp**
<?php

    echo $this->Form->create('add');
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->submit('submit');
    echo $this->Form->end();

?>
```

dbname: exercise; table: request;
goal: all inputted data must be in the db.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: And where is that FlashHelper and whitch line is 90? How do you you flashheper? all of this code seems unrelated

Comment: Error: Unsupported operand types 
File: C:\wamp\www\newsletter\lib\Cake\View\Helper\FlashHelper.php 
Line: 90
$message = $options + $message;

Comment: Also, what version of Cake are you using ?

Comment: IN PHP string concatenation is made with `.` (dot) not `+` sign.

Comment: CakePHP 2 because my PHP version is just 5.3, sir Antoniossss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FlashHelper` to set yor flash messages, not `Session->flash` 
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/flash.html

```
// In your Controller

public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session','Flash');

$this->Flash->set('The user has been saved.', array(
    'element' => 'success'
));
```